# How to fix ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTpResponse' from 'django.http'

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

After several trials, I still get the same

`ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTpResponse' from 'django.http' (/Users/mac/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py) after running '$ python manage.py runserver'`

in the terminal. Can someone please enlighten me with this issue? Thanks!

The code below were originally taken from the Django tutorial on its official website.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HTTpResponse

def index(request):    
    return HTTpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Comment: It is `HttpResponse`, not `HTTpResponse`.

Comment: Python language is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks all for your help on my silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

if u are using(httpresponse) this in views.py(django = 3.0.5  python = 3.8.2)

try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
```

(make sure its in camel case)
hope this will help

Comment: Thanks Aman...This way worked with me on On Mac. (django = 3.0.6 python = 3.8.2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):    
      return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Python is a case sensitive language,here camelCase are used and follow this.I think,it will work

Comment: I don't understand your point about camelCase. HttpResponse isn't camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

What was the reason for the random capitalization?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks all for your help on my silly mistake!